# std::map< MyClass, std::vector<MyClass> > Segment fault. Oddness

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, stdvector, stdmap

SOLVED:
Thanks figured it out thanks to dominic hamon.
It all boils down to trying to call a function on a *kinda* null object. It could use parts of the object but not others.

I had no idea that this could even happen.

Question

I have experienced an odd segmentation fault with a

```
std::map< IntVector3, std::vector<IntVector3> >.
```

In my MyClass.hpp file I make this a private property:

```
std::map< IntVector3, std::vector< IntVector3 > > recurData;
```

In my MyClass.cpp file in the constructor for MyClass i can run

```
 std::vector< IntVector3 > pt;
 pt.push_back(IntVector3(1,2,3));
 recurData[IntVector3(1,2,3)] = pt;
```

This runs correctly and i don't get a fault.

Later in the program i call a function in MyClass that does the same thing, altering of recurData. Not in the constructor. This causes a segmentation fault. There is no other change to my knowledge that affects recurData.

The implementable of IntVector3 is:
http://pastebin.com/Hc83xapk

There is a lot of extra operators that i added that are unneeded (>=,<=...).
(I tried to follow the rule of 3)

The only real oddness is the < operator. This uses a std::string to compare. This quick hack should work for all x,y,z if they are under 99.

Thanks for the help, this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: You have to make sure that your key type's `operator<` is a *strict weak ordering*. Double-check if that's the case.

Comment: What line of code does the seg-fault correspond to?  Have you tried reducing your code down to a minimal test case?

Comment: stacktrace? Where does the segfault occur? What about the copy constructor of IntVector3?

Comment: I am think my operator< is strict weak ordering. It is just a std::string.

Comment: The segfault occurs at the last line. Adding an element to the map. All i can get for debug info off of gdb is: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
at 0x000000000041881a in function std::_Rb_tree<IntVector3, std::pair<IntVector3 const, std::vector<IntVector3, std::allocator<IntVector3> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<IntVector3 const, std::vector<IntVector3, std::allocator<IntVector3> > > >, std::less<IntVector3>, std::allocator<std::pair<IntVector3 const, std::vector<IntVector3, std::allocator<IntVector3> > > > >::size()
at /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_tree.h:671

Comment: Without more information my best guess would be that you're calling the method that is not a constructor on an invalid MyClass object. Maybe it's been deleted, maybe it's through a NULL pointer.

Comment: Element addition may fail (e.g. cause a stack overflow) if the ordering isn't OK (there might be a non-terminating recursion). What is that string that's getting compared? Try using your own predicate maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a string to achieve a comparison function is (a) massively inefficient, and (b) broken.  It will not provide you a *strict-weak ordering*, which is what is required for `std::map`.  In particular, it is not going to be transitive, i.e. if `a < b` and `b < c`, it won't necessarily give you that `a < c`.  This is going to totally mess up `std::map`.

A typical implementation of `<` would be something like:

```
bool operator< (const IntVector3 &a, const IntVector3 &b)
{
    if (a.z < b.z) { return true; }
    if (a.z > b.z) { return false; }
    if (a.y < b.y) { return true; }
    if (a.y > b.y) { return false; }
    return (a.x < b.x);
}
```

Comment: Just changed that in my IntVector3.hpp file. I complete alternately agree that the way i was doing was terrible. thanks for the alternative. This did not fix the problem though.

Comment: Ok, in that case you're going to need to provide a complete, *minimal* example of some calling code that causes the problem.  Please strip out any unnecessary/redundant code!

Comment: I am on my way to figuring it out. I think it is something on the lines of a bad pointer. I will post back either way with a simplified code or a solution. Thanks for the help.